# localStorage "works" when the not defined error is thrown. dark mode theme not saving

Tags: reactjs, next.js, darkmode

If I remove the if statement that checks if its running on the browser, the dark/light mode theme saves whenever the page is reloaded. However, I get the localStorage is not defined. Once I put in the if statement, the dark/light mode theme doesn't save whenever the page is reloaded and is always set to dark mode.

Another thing I noticed is whenever I reload the page while in dark mode I can click the toggle the first time and it works. If I reload the page while in light mode, I have to click the toggle twice for the theme to switch.

```
  var state = '';
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    state = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');
  }
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(state || 'dark');
  const toggleMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(darkMode == 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark');
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode', darkMode);
  }, [darkMode]);
```

```
<BsFillMoonStarsFill onClick={toggleMode} className="cursor-pointer text-2xl dark:hidden" />
<BsSunFill onClick={toggleMode} className="hidden cursor-pointer text-2xl dark:text-white dark:inline" />
```

The dark mode switcher itself basically works, it's just the saving theme part that I'm having trouble with.

Most of the solutions I found say to use: `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')` but I don't know why it's not working for me. I think I might not be understanding the flow of the code whenever the page loads and whenever the buttons are toggled.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need to use `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')`. You need to set `state` variable to the value stored in `localStorage`. If `localStorage` is empty then set the localStorage with default value. Then whenever `darkMode` changes you update the `localStorage`. Please do not use `==` (double equals) ever to compare values, always use `===` (triple equals). Please always use variables for hardcoded/default values. It's even better if variable name is all caps as it improves readability and makes updation and debugging way easier.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const DEFAULT_THEME = "dark";
  let state = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
  //if localstorage does not have darkmode set , add a new item(darkMode)
  if (state === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("darkMode", DEFAULT_THEME);
    state = DEFAULT_THEME;
    console.log("state is null, added darMode to Local-Storage");
  }
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(state);
  //Update localStorage when state changes
  useEffect(() => {
    //do not update when the state: darkmode is initialized
    darkMode && localStorage.setItem("darkMode", darkMode);
  }, [darkMode]);

  const toggleMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(darkMode === "dark" ? "light" : "dark");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      Theme: {darkMode}
      <button onClick={toggleMode}>toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: _Please do not use == (double equals) ever to compare values as it equates object references and not values,_ - this is incorrect. The `==` operator compares values _and_ attempts type coercion (so number can be equal to string, for example). For references (so, objects, arrays, functions) `==` and `===` work the same.

Comment: @mbo Thanks for the correction. In a hurry, I mixed that up. Removed that part of the explanation

Comment: Why do I not need to use `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')`? Without it, I will get this error: `ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined` and the build will not compile.

Comment: See, if you have a server-side component in react it will not have access to objects like **window** and **localStorge api** as they are only part of the DOM which is generated by the browser(client-side). Hence, you will not be able to use localStorge it will be undefined. Therefore, we check whether the component is running on the browser or not by using `if( typeof window!== undefined)`  as window object will be undefined on the server.